# (Pandas) How to find the total duration of events in a given period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe `df_periods` with start and end datetimes for each relevant time period. Eg: (datetimes shown as numbers)

```
Index  tStart  tEnd
0      0       10
1      10      18
2      18      27
3      27      40
```

and then I have a dataframe `df_sensor` with the start and end datetime of each sensor activation

```
Index  Period  tOn  tOff
0      0       1    3
1      0       5    8
2      0       7    9 
3      1       12   16
4      1       14   16
5      3       27   30
6      3       33   35
```

From these two, I want to find the total amount of time during each period in which any sensor was active, to produce a `df_periods` like

```
Index  tStart  tEnd  active
0      0       10    6
1      10      18    4
2      18      27    0
3      27      40    5
```

Complications:

- `df_sensor` contains activation events from different sensors, so some events overlap in time. For `df_periods['active']`, I do not want these overlaps to be double counted.

Notes:

- `df_sensor` is sorted by `'tOn'`
- Every sensor activation happens within the bounds of a single period

Constructors:

```
d_periods = [[0,10], [10,18],[18,27],[27,40]]
df_periods = pd.DataFrame(d_periods, columns = ['tStart','tEnd'])
d_sensor = [[0,1,3],[0,5,8],[0,7,9],[1,12,16],[1,14,16],[3,27,30],[3,33,35]]
df_sensor = pd.DataFrame(d_sensor, columns = ['Period', 'tOn','tOff'])
```

Comment: How are you calculating the values in the `active` column?

Comment: @Zero It's the sum of differences between tOn and tOff of all the events that happen in the given period, without double counting overlapping events. E.g: for period 0, counting events 0,1,2, the duration would be (3-1)+(9-5) = 2+4 = 6. Note how events 1 and 2 overlap.

Comment: please provide the constructors of your DataFrames

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Get non-overlapping ranges for your sensors
2. `merge_asof` to get all active times
3. `groupby` and `nunique` to get the count

```
#get range from tOn to tOff for each row
df_sensor["Active"] = df_sensor.apply(lambda row: list(range(row["tOn"], row["tOff"])), axis=1)

#explode to get one row per active time
active = df_sensor.explode("Active").astype({"Active": "int64"}).sort_values("Active")

merged = pd.merge_asof(active, df_periods, left_on="Active", right_on="tStart")

df_periods["active"] = df_periods["tStart"].map(merged.groupby("tStart")["Active"].nunique()).fillna(0)

>>> df_periods
   tStart  tEnd  active
0       0    10     6.0
1      10    18     4.0
2      18    27     0.0
3      27    40     5.0
```